# Trouble Renaming PDF file in Email/SMTP Script

Tags: python

I found a script that will attach a PDF file into an email. However the PDF attached had a full path name of "C:\User\12345.pdf". I want the file name to just have "12345.pdf" so i used os.path.basename. Now every time i open the PDF in the email i get an error "Adobe could not open '12345.pdf' because its either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged. My code is below.

```
addr_to = 'test@test.com'
addr_from = 'test@test.com'
# Define SMTP email server details
smtp_server = 'test.com'
port = '25'
attachmentfilename = os.path.basename('C:\User\' + filename)

# Construct email
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['To'] = addr_to
msg['From'] = addr_from
msg['Subject'] = 'Subject HERE'

# Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).

text = "This is a test message.\nText and html."
print(text)
html = "This is a test message.\nText and html."
f"""
                <b>{master_name}</b>
                <br /><br />
                Test TEXT<br/><br/><br/>
                Thank You,<br/>
                Test Deptt<br/>
                """

# Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html.
part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
part.add_header('Content-Disposition',
                'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(attachmentfilename))
msg.attach(part)
# Attach parts into message container.
# According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this case
# the HTML message, is best and preferred.
msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)

# Send the message via an SMTP server
s = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port)
s.sendmail(addr_from, addr_to, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

Comment: It's probably best to use pathlib instead of os.path, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're actually attaching the PDF, just a pointer to the file on disk. That's why it can't find it when you just call it 12345.pdf. Similarly, you will find that even though it seems to work for you with the full name 'c:/user/12345.pdf', another person on another computer won't be able to open it (because the file isn't on their computer).

I'm not familiar with the smtp library or MIMEMultipart stuff, so I can't offer you the code to make it work - I'm sure you can look it up though.

---

Also, I suggest that you avoid using literal backslashes in your file path strings. Use `os.path.join` to build a path, which will use the separator that is appropriate for your platform, be it Windows, Linux, OSX, etc. The main benefit here is that you will avoid accidentally building the wrong path because Python interprets something in your path as an escape (`\n`, `\b`, `\t`, etc).